# how to retrieve sector and industry for a list of tickers with python?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, yfinance

I have a list of tickers (below: tick1) that comes from the Earnings Report.
I would like to add the "shortname", "sector" and the "industry" next to the ticker while creating a dataframe.
Unfortunately, the columns are always shuffeling up a bit and they are not matched properly. for instance: VFC --> sector: technology; industry: Semiconductors, which is wrong. It should be sector: Consumer Cyclical; industry: Apparel Manufacturing

Here is my code below: can you please help to adjust it?

---tickers to be read---
import yfinance as yf

```
with open("/Users/Doc/AB/Earnings/tickers.txt") as fh:
    tick1 = fh.read().split()
```

tickers in txt file
ABOS
ACRX
ADI
ADMP
ADOCY
AER
AGYS
AINV
ALBO
ALLT
AMAT
AMPS
AOZOY
ARCO
AREC
ARZGY
ATAI
AUTO
AVAL
AXDX
BAH
BBAR
BBWI
BHIL
BJ
BKYI
BLBX
BPCGY
BPTH
BRDS
BZFD
CAAP
CAE
CALT
CCHWF
CCSI
CELC
CFRHF
CGEN
CINT
CLSN
CMRX
CRLBF
CRXT
CSCO
CSWI
CVSI
CWBHF
CWBR
DAC
DADA
DE
DECK
DESP
DLO
DOYU
DTST
DUOT
EAST
EBR
EBR.B
EDAP
ENJY
EVTV
EXP
FATH
FL
FLO
FSI
FTK
FUV
FXLV
GAN
GBOX
GDS
GLBE
GLOB
GNLN
GOED
GOGL
GRAB
GRAMF
GRCL
HD
HOOK
HPK
HUYA
HWKN
HYRE
IBEX
IGIC
IKT
IMPL
INLB
INLX
INVO
IONM
IONQ
IPW
IPWR
ISUN
ITCTY
JBI
JD
JHX
JMIA
KALA
KBNT
KEYS
KMDA
KORE
KSLLF
KSS
KULR
LOW
LTRY
LUNA
LVLU
MARK
MBT
MCG
MCLD
MDWD
MDWT
MIGI
MIRO
MNDY
MNMD
MNRO
MSADY
MSGM
MUFG
MVST
NEXCF
NGS
NNOX
NOVN
NRDY
NRGV
NU
NXGN
OBSV
OEG
OMQS
ONON
PANW
PASG
PCYG
PEAR
PLNHF
PLX
PTE
PTN
PXS
QIPT
QRHC
QTEK
QUIK
RCRT
RDY
REE
REED
REKR
RKLB
RMED
RMTI
ROST
RSKD
RYAAY
SANW
SCVL
SDIG
SE
SHLS
SHPW
SHWZ
SLGG
SNPS
SPRO
SQM
SRAD
SSYS
SUNL
SUNW
SUPV
SYN
SYRS
TCEHY
TCRT
TCS
TGI
TGT
THBRF
TJX
TKOMY
TLLTF
TME
TRMR
TSEM
TSHA
TTWO
TXMD
USWS
VBLT
VERB
VEV
VFC
VIPS
VJET
VOXX
VTRU
VVOS
VWE
VYGVF
VYNT
WEBR
WEDXF
WEJO
WIX
WMS
WMT
WRBY
WYY
YALA
YOU
ZIM

---adding the shortname, sector, industry ---
from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd

```
symbols = tick1

tickers = Ticker(symbols, asynchronous=True)

datasi = tickers.get_modules("summaryProfile quoteType")
dfsi = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datasi).T

dataframes = [pd.json_normalize([x for x in dfsi[module] if isinstance(x, dict)]) for 
module in ['summaryProfile', 'quoteType']]

dfsi = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
dfsi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['TSHA', 'GRAMF', 'VFC', 'ABOS', 'INLX', 'INVO', 'IONM', 'IONQ']

tickers = Ticker(symbols, asynchronous=True)

datasi = tickers.get_modules("summaryProfile quoteType")
dfsi = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datasi).T
dataframes = [pd.json_normalize([x for x in dfsi[module] if isinstance(x, dict)]) for
module in ['summaryProfile', 'quoteType']]

dfsi = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)

dfsi = dfsi.set_index('symbol')
dfsi = dfsi.loc[symbols]

print(dfsi[['industry', 'sector']])
```

Output

```
                                      industry             sector
symbol                                                           
TSHA                             Biotechnology         Healthcare
GRAMF   Drug Manufacturers—Specialty & Generic         Healthcare
VFC                      Apparel Manufacturing  Consumer Cyclical
ABOS                             Biotechnology         Healthcare
INLX                      Software—Application         Technology
INVO                           Medical Devices         Healthcare
IONM                   Medical Care Facilities         Healthcare
IONQ                         Computer Hardware         Technology
```

Try the following. Set the column'symbol' as indexes.
And send it to the ticker list. Again, you need to check.

I have run the ticker 'VFC' several times: VFC industry---Apparel Manufacturing, sector---Consumer Cyclical.